# Platform Dependent Encoding issues in Java

Tags: java, encoding

Noticed this behavior while troubleshooting a file generation issue in a piece of java code that's moved from AIX to LINUX sever.

```
Charset.defaultCharset();
```

returns `ISO-8859-1` on AIX, `UTF-8` on Linux, and `windows-1252` on my Windows 7. With that said, I am trying to figure out why on the Linux machine, `nlength` = 24 (3 bytes per alphanumeric character) whereas on AIX and Windows it is 8.

```
    String inString = "ABC12345";
    byte[] ebcdicByte = new byte[inString.length()];
    System.out.println("Length:"+inString.getBytes("Cp1047").length);
    ebcdicByte = inString.getBytes("Cp1047").);
    String ebcdicString = new String( ebcdicByte);
    int nlength = ebcdicString.getBytes().length;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on fge's answer...

Your observation is occurring because `new String(ebcdicByte)` and `ebcdicString.getBytes()` use the platform's default charset.

ISO-8859-1 and windows-1252 are one-byte charsets.  In those charsets, one byte always represents one character.  So in AIX and Windows, when you do `new String(ebcdicByte)`, you will always get a String whose character count is identical to your byte array's length.  Similarly, converting a String back to bytes will use a one-to-one mapping.

But in UTF-8, one character does not necessarily correspond to one byte.  In UTF-8, bytes 0 through 127 are single-byte representations of characters, but all other values are part of a multi-byte sequence.

However, not just any sequence of bytes with their high bit set is a valid UTF-8 sequence.  If you give an UTF-8 decoder a sequence of bytes that isn't a properly encoded UTF-8 byte sequence, it is considered malformed.  `new String` will simply map malformed sequences to a special default character, usually "�" (`'\ufffd'`).  That behavior can be changed by explicitly creating your own CharsetDecoder and calling its [onMalformedInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onMalformedInput-java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction-) method, rather than just relying on `new String(byte[])`.

So, the `ebcdicByte` array contains this EBCDIC representation of "ABC12345":

```
C1 C2 C3 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5
```

None of those are valid UTF-8 byte sequences, so `ebcdicString` ends up as `"\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd"` which is "��������".

Your last line of code calls `ebcdicString.getBytes()`, which again does not specify a character set, which means the default charset will be used.  Using UTF-8, "�" gets encoded as three bytes, EF BF BD.  Since there are eight of those in `ebcdicString`, you get 3×8=24 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunterstanding things.

This is Java.

There are `byte`s. There are `char`s. And there is the default encoding.

When translating from `byte`s to `char`s, you have to [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).

When translating from `char`s to `byte`s, you have to [encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html).

And of course, apart from very limited charsets **you will never have a 1-1 char-byte mapping**.

If you see problems with encoding/decoding, the cause is pretty simple: somewhere in your code (with luck, in only one place; if not lucky, in several places) you failed to specify the charset to use when decoding and encoding.

Also note that by default, the encoding/decoding behaviour on failure it to [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html#REPLACE) unmappable `char`/`byte` sequences.

All this to say: **a `String` does not have an encoding**. Sure, it is a series of `char`s and a `char` is a primitive type; but it could just as well have been a stream of carrier pigeons, the two basic processes remain the same: you need to decode from bytes and you need to encode to bytes; if either part fails you end with meaningless byte sequences/mutant carrier pigeons.

Comment: I like when you explain things so easily understandable

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the charset in the second to last line.

```
 String ebcdicString = new String( ebcdicByte,"Cp1047");
```

as already pointed out, you always have to specify the charset when encoding/decoding.